# how to do the access control for PubNub subscribe

Tags: node.js

guys,

We want to control the subscribe for a channel: only the subscriber with the authKey can listen to the channel. Others even with the subscribeKey can not get the message from the channel.

Publisher code:

```
var channel = "customerId_123456abcef";
var pubnub = new PubNub({
    publishKey : 'pub-c-123456abcef',
    subscribeKey : 'sub-c-123456abcef',
    authKey : 'accountId_123456abcef'
});

pubnub.publish({
    channel : channel,
    message : "bluh bluh"
}, function(status, response) {
    if (response == null) {
        console.log('publish() response is null.')
    } else {
        console.log(response.timetoken);
    }
})
```

Subscriber code:

```
var channel = 'customerId_123456abcef';
pubnub = new PubNub({
    subscribeKey : 'sub-c-123456abcef',
})

pubnub.addListener({
    status: function(statusEvent) {
        if (statusEvent.category === "PNConnectedCategory") {
            console.log('Hi, I start to listen ....... ', channel);
        }
    },
    message: function(message) {
        console.log(message.timetoken);
    },
    presence: function(presenceEvent) {
        // handle presence
    }
})
console.log("Subscribing................... ", channel);
pubnub.subscribe({
    channels: [channel]
});
```

Since there is no authKey in subscriber code, it should not get the message from the channel. but actually it can.
We look at PubNub website, did not find an useful example. In its v4.0.6 github source code testing section, we can not find either.

test/integration/endpoints/access.test.js

test/integration/endpoints/publish.test.js

test/integration/endpoints/subscribe.test.js

if any one knows some sample code to do the access control, Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub JavaScript Access Manager Docs/Tutorials

The reason your subscriber was able to subscribe to the channel without an auth-key with proper `read` permission on that channel is that your keys were granted `read` access at the sub-key (app) level which overrides the need for an auth-key. Revoking the sub-key grant will force clients to have an auth-key with proper permissions.

To revoke all permissions granted at the sub-key level, run this code once:

```js
var PubNub = require('pubnub');
var pubnub = new PubNub({
    publishKey : 'pub-c-ddf5ed7c-redacted', // add you full pub-key here
    subscribeKey : 'sub-c-80140724-6381-11e6-ac7d-02ee2ddab7fe',
    secretKey: 'sec-c-YWRjNGFiNmQtZTZ-redacted'
});
pubnub.grant(
    {
        read: false,
        write: false,
        manage: false
    },
    function (status) {
        console.log(status);
    }
);
```

In addition, you might have channel level grants that also override the need for an auth-key on that particular channel.

Try the [PubNub JavaScript SDK v4 API Reference](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api-reference-sdk-v4#init) and [PubNub JavaScript SDK v4 Tutorials](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pam-security).

Initialize `PubNub` object with the `authKey` that has the correct permissions (`read` for the target channel) that were granted to it by your server.

```js
var pubnub = new PubNub({
    subscribeKey: "mySubscribeKey",
    authKey: "my_AuthKey"
})
```